# How to get the social networking profile information through Email Id?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I am working on iphone application.I wanted to get the social networking (facebook,twitter, etc) profile details by giving email id as query.  Is there any method to get the profile ?

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook you can try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5247066/580173

For twitter this this not possible. You can use oAuth to authenticate the user and get the profile.

For LinkedIn I believe it's also not possible. LinkedIn doesn't communicate the emailaddress anywhere in their API.
See this forum post: https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1131

Comment: For Facebook i tried and its working fine now... In Some application like Smartr for iphone (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1FoOKX5XkQ), they did integrate facebook and twitter  profile directly just by using information like emailid name available in the iphone addresbook. They dont even ask the user to login. How it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're wanting to just add the social profile *links* to a user's profile inside your app...correct? (If you want to actually allow your users to *post* to their various social media accounts, your best bet is to go ahead and let users sign into each individual account via OAuth.)

If you're looking to get public social info via email address, your free options for a simple solution are pretty limited. Each different social network has its own method, so you'd need to build out a different process to query each social network you want to support. Without more info on which networks you want to support, there are any number of different answers to this question - so I'll just say your best bet is to check out the developer docs of whichever social networks you want to use.

If you're looking for a paid solution, you might try [FullContact](http://www.fullcontact.com/developer/) (full disclosure - I work for them). The Person API pretty much does exactly what you're looking for - pulling all public social media profiles associated with a particular email ID. API docs are [here](http://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/).

However, it is a paid solution, which may not be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.