# Getting image by email from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to some articles I've read, to get image I need to obtain userId and then I can get the user's avatar image. However it is said that the functionality for getting userId by email has been deprecated and not working anymore.

However, I am using Sparrow mail app – and when I am logged in via Facebook, the application seems to obtain the images for users in my mailbox – how do they do that?

[image]

This should be the way [How can I get Facebook Profile image from email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851842/how-can-i-get-facebook-profile-image-from-email) - but according to https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/453298034751100/ it should not work anymore. So what are they actually using?

Comment: If you have the FB User ID, you can request the image via `https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture`

Comment: I know, the problem is getting user id from email.